# How to add correct way to my static in Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

Important from my app.js file:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var profile = require('./controllers/profile-controller'); //require my controller (profile-controller.js)
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/user', profile);
```

When I go to 'mysite.com/user' - it works fine, but when I go to 'mysite.com/user/user1', my CSS and images ain't loading. Here is my controller file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// route for www.mysite.com/user
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile',{ title: 'Profile' });

});
// route for www.mysite.com/user/user1 
router.get('/:id([A-Za-z0-9_]{5})', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    res.render('profile',{ title: 'Profile' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Console gives me that:[image]

So why I have the same route for both pages, but one of them working well, but second gives 404 for static files?

Comment: You can see it on the image you have attached. When you go to `/user`, it loads images from `/img/...`. But when you go to `/user/user1`, images are loaded from `/user/img/...`. Check how your resources are being referenced.

Comment: @ex0dm3nt but how to fix it? I am trying different ways, but can't fix it...

Comment: could you please also add html file of that `profile` template? Have you tried putting in the entire path, like `res.render('/templates/profile',{ title: 'Profile' });` or whatever the file path is to that file?

Comment: @ex0dm3nt here is github repo: https://github.com/BimBoss/sample-example . It's a simple express-generator app, but I add image 'wow.png' to images folder and another one route, to routes/users.js. So if you run (npm start) server and go to localhost:3000 everything is okay, if you go to localhost:3000/users, it's still ok, but if you go localhost;3000/users/username, image path become broken and img status is 404 .... like in my own project...

Comment: Could you please try just one more thing? In `index.hbs` file, instead of `src="images/wow.png"` put `src="/public/images/wow.png"` or `src="/images/wow.png"` .

Comment: @ex0dm3nt wow, ipressive. You are incredible! Thanks a lot. Wish you all best! Add to answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it right away :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.hbs` file, you have `src="images/wow.png"`, which is a relative path to your image resource. So when you go to `/user/user1`, it just adds the `/user` to your image resource path.

Instead of `src="images/wow.png"` try putting `src="/public/images/wow.png"` or `src="/images/wow.png"`.